# MS Access Msg box VBOKonly if number field data is greater than 1

Tags: ms-access

I want Msgbox for user to remind something if user enters a number greater than 1 in a form Number field.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post your form code for this input field?  What would you like to trigger the message box?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from entering a number > 1, set "<=1" as **validation rule** for the field, and your Msgbox text as validation text.

Otherwise use the `AfterUpdate` event of the form field:

```
Private Sub myNumberField_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.myNumberField > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Hello user, I have a message for you!", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry It is not what i am trying to achieve. If user enters a value greater than one, a msgbox with custom message i set for user.